# Any suggestion on the best way to build a serial port script?

Tags: scripting, serial-port

I need to configure daily dozens of devices through serial port. The config is at it follows:

- Wait for boot (i.e. a specific line appears).
- Enter a sequence of commands.
- Do a 'print' to check everything is right.
- Move to next device.

It doesn't seem complicated, and I really need to automate it. I'm not an expert programmer, but I find my ways.

What can you suggest me to get started? Where should I look on? In particular, any great API out there that would do the dirty job for me? I'm using Windows, but I could get Linux too if really needed. 
The one language that I've studied is C. But I'm open to something new as long as it can be done fast.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

That looks like a task for `expect`:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set timeout 20
spawn "terminal-program"
expect "a specific line"
send "sequence_of_commands"
expect "prompt >"
send "print"
```

and put that in a bash-loop.